# Is this websocket causing an infinite loop?

Tags: node.js, websocket, node-red

I'm using node red but the concept is the same for all websockets.

For demonstration purposes this image represents a basic chat app. 
When a user sends a message to the websocket, the websocket will send it out to all users as seen in the nodes here:

[image]

I am not getting any errors but isn't this type of system being called infinity?

I have looked around and this seems to be general practice. Am I just misunderstanding how sockets work?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not an infinite loop. Data transmitted via WebSockets has a direction, so a server won't process data that it sent, only data that it received from someone else. (Now it's a different story if you ever connect two of these servers to each other somehow. It'd be like packet storms from old hubs.)